# HTML5 videos jagged/pixellated.

Tags: linux, youtube, chromium, html5

I'm using Chromium browser on Linux operating system but any html5 videos (like Youtube videos) are not resizing properly. This means that if I want to watch Youtube videos lower than 480p the videos look pixellated and if higher than 480p then the video (especially the edges of objects) look jagged.

The thing is: the videos worked perfectly until just a week ago.

Here are the things that have not worked:

1. Disabling/enabling "Override software rendering list" on chrome/flags
2. Restarting the computer
3. Disable hardware-accelerated video decode (cannot enable/disable on Linux).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Chromium from Linux, because the chromium browser is a little buggy. html5 support on it is bad, and it crashes easily.

Download google chrome, from the website and install it from ubuntu software center.

If this does not work, then sorry, I can't help you.